# Non-buffering StreamReader?

Tags: java, stream, inputstream, streamreader

Is there non-buffering stream reader implementation somewhere?

I have created my streams in the following way

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFilename);
CountingInputStream countingStream = new CountingInputStream(inputStream);
InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(countingStream, Charset.forName("utf8"));
```

and `countingStream` indicates position 8192 from the very beginning. This means that reader reads 8192 bytes despite I am reading char by char.

Is there any reader without this feature?

[CountingInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CountingInputStream.html) is from Apache Commons IO API.

Comment: Do you see the same thing without your 'CountingInputStream'?

Comment: Without `CountingInputStream` a have no means to see position at all. This is from here http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CountingInputStream.html

Comment: why do you want a non-buffering Reader?

Comment: Question title should be non-buffering counting stream reader

Comment: @jtahlborn because I have `BufferedReader` already for use if I want. No need to make buffering inside normal reader too.

Comment: @Miserable why? How do you know it is counting reader, who buffers?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that is what you were looking for -- that you don't want buffering and you do want to see position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would *want* one (seems rather inefficient), but you could implement one yourself using [CharsetDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html).

Comment: I've had a need for one when I decided to implement my own tiny web server. I had to read chars until the empty line separating the headers from the body of the HTTP request, and then read the body as bytes, directly from the underlying input stream. I indeed had to implement it by myself because of the buffering of the InputStreamReader.